# Can't compare button icon to another icon

Tags: java, swing, compare, icons, jbutton

I am overriding the actionListener. All of the buttons besides "playbutton" have an image attached as an icon (button1, button2, button3). Every time a button is pressed, it should compare its icon to the prepared ImageIcon "livePicture" and if they are the same, it should go with the "Escaped()" method. Otherwise, the program will run the "Died()" method.
However, at least with the current code, it only uses "Died()". This, I guess, means that there is something wrong with the ifs that compare the images, but that is the only way of comparison I found on the internet.
Also, keep in mind that this is my first project, so it may seem a little cluttered.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Frame
{
private final int WIDTH = 1024;
private final int HEIGHT = 768;

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JLabel human;
private JTextArea text;
private JTextArea deathMessage;
private ImageIcon livePicture;
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JButton button3;
private GridBagConstraints gbc;
private ActionListener actionListener;
private JButton playButton;
private Border border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
private Font font = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 20);

public Frame()
{
    Quest survival = new Quest();

    actionListener = e -> {
        if (e.getSource() == playButton) //playbutton works fine
        {
            if (!survival.IsEmpty())
            {
                AppendQuest(survival.GetQuest());
                survival.RemoveQuest();
            }
            else
            {
                Escaped();
            }
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == button1) //button1 action
        {
            if (button1.getIcon().toString() != livePicture.toString())
            {
                Died();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!survival.IsEmpty())
                {
                    AppendQuest(survival.GetQuest());
                    survival.RemoveQuest();
                }
                else
                {
                    Escaped();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == button2) //button2 action
        {
            if (button2.getIcon().toString() != livePicture.toString())
            {
                Died();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!survival.IsEmpty())
                {
                    AppendQuest(survival.GetQuest());
                    survival.RemoveQuest();
                }
                else
                {
                    Escaped();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == button3) //button3 action
        {
            if (button3.getIcon().toString() != livePicture.toString())
            {
                Died();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!survival.IsEmpty())
                {
                    AppendQuest(survival.GetQuest());
                    survival.RemoveQuest();
                }
                else
                {
                    Escaped();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    //I left the rest of the constructor for bonus info
    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    human = new JLabel(ImageSize(200, 200, "res/human.png"));
    text = new JTextArea("You have lost in the forest. Now you have to find " +
            "your way back.");
    FormatText(text);
    deathMessage = new JTextArea();
    frame.setTitle("Shady Path");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    playButton = new JButton();
    playButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
    playButton.setFont(font);
    playButton.setText("Play");
    playButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    playButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    playButton.setBorder(border);

    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    panel.add(human, gbc);

    gbc.insets = new Insets(30, 0, 0, 0);
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    panel.add(text, gbc);

    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(50, 0, 68, 0);
    panel.add(playButton, gbc);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void AppendQuest(Vector<String> event)
{
    panel.removeAll();

    panel.add(human, gbc);
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 30, 0);
    text.setText(event.remove(0));
    FormatText(text);
    panel.add(text, gbc);
    deathMessage.setText(event.remove(0));
    FormatText(deathMessage);
    livePicture = ImageSize(50, 50, event.remove(0));

    Collections.shuffle(event);
    ImageIcon picture1 = ImageSize(50, 50, event.get(0)); //setting button1
    button1 = new JButton();
    button1.addActionListener(actionListener);
    button1.setIcon(picture1);
    button1.setBorder(border);
    ImageIcon picture2 = ImageSize(50, 50, event.get(1)); //setting button2
    button2 = new JButton();
    button2.addActionListener(actionListener);
    button2.setIcon(picture2);
    button2.setBorder(border);
    ImageIcon picture3 = ImageSize(50, 50, event.get(2)); //setting button3
    button3 = new JButton();
    button3.addActionListener(actionListener);
    button3.setIcon(picture3);
    button3.setBorder(border);
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(50, 360, 100, 0);
    panel.add(button1, gbc);
    gbc.insets = new Insets(50, 77, 100, 77);
    panel.add(button2, gbc);
    gbc.insets = new Insets(50, 0, 100, 360);
    panel.add(button3, gbc);

    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
}

private void Escaped()
{
    //Unnecessary info
}

private void Died()
{
    //Unnecessary info
}
//This just resizes the images
private ImageIcon ImageSize(int x, int y, String fileName)
{
    BufferedImage baseImg = null;
    try {
        baseImg = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Image resizedImg = baseImg.getScaledInstance(x, y, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon IconImg = new ImageIcon(resizedImg);
    return IconImg;
}

private void FormatText(JTextArea baseText)
{
    //Unnecessary info
}
}
```

EDIT:
Here is also an example of what vector could go as an "event" in "AppendQuest"

```
Vector<String> items2 = new Vector<>();
items2.add("You are kind of disoriented. What will you use to find the right way?" +
            " moss, sun or tree barks");
items2.add("Unfortunately you didn't orient yourself well enough. Now, you " +
            "will roam through the forest forever.");
items2.add("res/orientation_sun.png");
items2.add("res/orientation_moss.png");
items2.add("res/orientation_sun.png");
items2.add("res/orientation_tree_bark.png");
```

Comment: Time to do some debugging

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare Objects with the .equals(Object) function:

```
if(!button.getIcon().equals(livePicture))
{
   Died();
}
else
{...}
```

The == operator checks the identity of objects or the value of native types (e.g. int).
That means:

```
int nr1 = 1;
int nr2  = 1;
if(nr1 == nr2) {...} //true -> int is a native type

String str1 = "test";
String str2 = "test";
if(str1 == str2) {...} //false -> Same content but not same objects
if(str1.equals(str2)) {...} //true -> Same content, different objects
```

//Edit:
Another problem might be that you remove the image-url from your vector while creating the livePicture:

```
livePicture = ImageSize(50, 50, event.remove(0));
```

The url is not in the list anymore when you create your buttons. The result is that the buttons will never have the same image as your livePicture has, unless you're changing it (do you?).

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't fix the issue. I am not sure what is happening, but it never concludes that they are equal

Comment: Actually, I didn't check that about image-url. You are right. This might be a bit of a problem